# I want to change the selected button to `primary` button. I am sending id to asp.net core and changing isSelected to true for the selected answer

Tags: angular

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="question.questionType == 4">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">
     <button 
         (click)="setanswer(answer.answerId)"   
         [value]="answer.isSelected" 
         class="me-2" 
         name="{{ answer.answerId }}">{{ answer.answerDescription }}
     </button>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Primary? are you talking about a css goal ?

Comment: yes but the value of answer.isSelected is coming from backend and i only want to change the button to primary button whose value is true for answer.isSelected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of alternatives, let's say you have this `css` class defined:

```css
.primary {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1) Property Binding -->
<button [class.primary]="answer.isSelected"></button>

<!-- 2) NgClass -->
<button [ngClass]="{ 'primary': answer.isSelected }"></button>

<!-- 3) ngStyle-->
<button [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': answer.isSelected ? 'green' : 'blue' }"></button>
```

Sidenote, in your button HTML definition, you need to use property binding for `name`, not `string interpolation`, all `html` attributes can be used in `Angular` with `property binding`

```html
 <button 
   (click)="setanswer(answer.answerId)"   
   [value]="answer.isSelected" 
   class="me-2" 
   [name]="answer.answerId">{{ answer.answerDescription }}
</button>
```

Comment: Ok so Now the only issue is that when i click the button it does not change into  primary button  unless i reload the page.