# Best pratice for a css' property with angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I don't understand why it uses "directive" to add css property.

I can understand for a dynamic css property but, for an easy and simple property, is using directives a good practice ? and if yes, why ?

example de simple property :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAnyDirective]'
})
export class AnyDirective {

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}
```

Comment: You can make use of directives to apply css to elements when it could be dynamic.
Otherwise i think this piece of code is not usefull.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929021/i-want-to-change-the-selected-button-to-primary-button-i-am-sending-id-to-asp/72930123#72930123

Comment: Ok,I think it was an exemple for a tutorial. For a simple css, I will use CSS.

Comment: Andres2142, no, I knew already how do. Thx